# Can the instagram api pull likes and comments from an account that I do not manage

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I want to pull likes and comments from any account that I specify. Can this be done with the Instagram API or do you have to have the accounts permissions to pull this info.

Essentially I want to be able to analyze this data without having log in credentials for the account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following the June 2016 changes to the API, you will need to invite the other users to be "Sandbox Users" of your API client. And even then, the access will be limited to their last 20 posts. Here's a [quick explanation of the new Instagram API](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.4z8g35g2s) rules.

TL;DR

> Sandbox users are other Instagram users that you “invite” to your
>   client. The main reason to do this is so that your app will then be
>   able to “see” their last twenty posts in addition to your own. In
>   other words, when they accept the invitation, they show up on the tiny
>   desert island where your app lives.

So you don't need their actual login credentials, but they do need to accept your invitation in order for it to work. The only other alternative is getting your app through the submission process to "go live" but there are very few use cases which they will accept anymore.